# Install bison 2.7 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 12.04

When I try to install bison on my ubuntu 14.04 using the command `sudo apt-get install bison`, the version 3 is installed.

I would like to downgrade bison to use the version 2.7.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I have  a better solution, Check my answer :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I installed last pkgs of bison (2.7.1) and libbison-dev (2.7.1) from Saucy and it worked like a charm.

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/140087283/libbison-dev_2.7.1.dfsg-1_amd64.deb
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/140087282/bison_2.7.1.dfsg-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libbison-dev_2.7.1.dfsg-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i bison_2.7.1.dfsg-1_amd64.deb
```

To prevent update manager from overwriting this package

```
apt-mark hold libbison-dev
apt-mark hold bison
```

Done.

Comment: To prevent update manager to overwrite this package `apt-mark hold libbison-dev` and `apt-mark hold bison`

Comment: On the odd chance you need the 32-bit versions, you can get the downloads from here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libbison-dev (I'm using Ubuntu 32-bit in a VM because I need to test some code on a 32-bit platform)

Comment: Hey, take a look at my solution :)

Comment: for i386, the links are: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/140087287/libbison-dev_2.7.1.dfsg-1_i386.deb   and http://launchpadlibrarian.net/140087286/bison_2.7.1.dfsg-1_i386.deb

Comment: I do not recommend to install those as there is no guarantee they come to your server without virus and rootkis.

Answer (score 4):

Just give the package version also as follows:

```
apt-get install pkg=version
```

and you can get all the available versions using `apt-cache showpkg bison`

Comment: I tried `apt-get install bison=2:2.7.1.dfsg-1` but `apt-get` still complain `E: Version '2:2.7.1.dfsg-1' for 'bison' was not found`

Comment: This will only work if bison 2.7 is there in the archives but it is not there. you can see it by running `apt-cache showpkg bison` to see the versions available. One easy way would be adding saucy dev repo just to install bison 2.7.

Comment: I fixed by manually installing it. I thought there is a clean way to do it :( . Any how, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

bison2 (2:2.7.1.dfsg-1-ppa1) is available from my ppa [here](https://launchpad.net/~rjvbertin/+archive/ubuntu/misc/+packages)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Indeed, my answer doesn't explain how to downgrade, and I should have clarified that my package installs bison 2.7.1 alongside the v3 version in "trusty". (I also wasn't aware I can now comment on posts!)

Answer (score 2):

You can install bison version 2.7 via [linuxbrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew).  Once you have installed linuxbrew by:

```
ruby -e "$(wget -O- https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"
```

and adding the following to the bottom of .bashrc or .zshrc:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

You can install Bison 2.7!

```
brew install bison27
```

Homebrew is meant for macs, so it will yell at you for not using your Mac properly if you run brew doctor.  As Macs already have Bison installed, it will refuse to finish the install.  You can safely force it by doing:

```
brew link bison27 --force
```

And now check bison -V to see you are using Bison 2.7!

Comment: linux brew shouldn't be a thing!

Comment: @Greg it's convenient for mac users that want a simple script to make their linux and mac homes feel the same