# How to install bison 2.7 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bison

How can I install bison (2.7.1) in Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) ?
I did specifying the version, but there is nothing to install.

```
$ sudo apt-get install bison=2.7.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.7.1' for 'bison' was not found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate  http://askubuntu.com/questions/444982/install-bison-2-7-in-ubuntu-14-04?lq=1

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/461961/529063